# Preventing unnecessary executions in Make due to lack of artifact

Tags: docker, makefile

I'm trying to use make to build, run, and deploy my python code in a Docker container.  The commands are pretty straight forward, but I'm having difficulties getting them to work like I want in a Makefile.

I have defined a rule for docker_build as follows:

```
docker_build: Dockerfile requirements.txt *.py
    docker build -t $(IMAGE_NAME) .
```

Any time my Dockerfile, requirements.txt, or any python file changes, I need to build a new image.  Once built, I don't want to execute the command until a dependency changes.  But, because I don't have a readily available artifact, the docker_build step always executes.

How can I prevent unnecessary builds?  I know that I could touch a file called 'docker_build', but I would need to do that for each step, and it would create a bunch of files I really don't want.  I suppose I could add them to .gitignore, and add them to my cleanup target, but that feels dirty.  There must be a better way.

Comment: `make` is entirely predicated on the concept of comparing timestamps of files on the filesystem to determine "out of date-ness".  In effect, make is using the filesystem as a database storing when files were last updated: make doesn't have any state of its own (its own database to keep last updated times).  So, no, there's no other way to do it (if you use make): you have to have some sort of local file on the filesystem telling make when the last time you ran the commands was... it has no other way to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a dummy artifact to keep track of when you last built:

```
docker_build: .docker_build
.PHONY: docker_build

.docker_build: Dockerfile requirements.txt *.py
    docker build -t $(IMAGE_NAME) .
    touch $@
```

The timestamp of .docker_build is used as a trigger to rebuild.   Don't forget to clean it.

--- edit ---

sorry, I just reread your last paragraph where you basically describe this, and then say you don't like it.    First, this is not uncommon practice if you don't have a reliable timestamp.  Basically you have to store the last build time somewhere, implying you need a file one way or another.   Often the filename is prefixed with a `.` to avoid it messing up ls's, etc.   But yes, it is an artifact, which must be cleaned and ignored by revision control (you can put it in an object directory as well, if that makes you feel better).